# What is the difference of a real Array and Array Iterator in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator

if we have: let myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4] , and if we do: myArr.values(); we will get Array Iterator [1, 2, 3, 4]. 
So, what's the difference of an array and an array Iterator?

Comment: You seem to be confused by the way they are getting logged in the console. Have a look at how they are actually used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare an array as `let myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4]`, it returns you an object of type Array. It has all the properties and methods associated with the Array type, like length, push, pop, etc.

[image: array options]

On the other hand, `myArr.values()` returns an iterator. The iterator is not the same as the original Array in the sense that it does not have the properties and methods of an Array. Instead, being an iterator, it has its own methods like `next`, etc that you can use to iterate over the values.

[image: iterator options]

Answer (score 5):

They have different purposes and functionalities:

- arrays are rooms, iterator is the room guards, allowing to move to next rooms
- Iterator allows you to traverse, e.g. next() can be called
- Iterator does not allow you to access via index, e.g. iterator[0]

[image]

```
const x = [1, 2, 3];
const iterator = x.values();

console.log(x[1]);    //OK -> 2
console.log(iterator[1]);  //   -> Undefined

console.log(iterator.next()); //OK -> 1
console.log(iterator.next()); //OK -> 2
console.log(iterator.next()); //OK -> 3
console.log(iterator.next()); //OK -> { value: undefined, done: true }
//x.next();         //✗Error: x.next is not a function
```

Comment: +1. And **arrays must be allocated in their entirety, but iterators are consumed only as necessary and thus can express sequences of unlimited size, such as the range of integers between 0 and Infinity** from mozilla docs but it is the good point too.

Answer (score 1):

An array is not the same thing as an iterator, though they're somewhat similar.

An array is a collection of data that you can call methods on (like `forEach` and `map`), and that you can pass to other array methods (like `concat`). Arrays also happen to be iterable (they have a `Symbol.iterator` method).

On the other hand, an iterator, or an array iterator, *only* provides functionality for iterating over the data; it doesn't allow for anything else. You cannot `push` to an iterator, or modify it, or extract values from certain indicies (without actually iterating over it). All you can do with an iterator is iterate, whereas with the full array, you can do many other things.

Here, there's rarely a use case for invoking `Array.prototype.values`, because the iterator it returns is identical to the iterator that would be used if you had iterated over the plain array (with for..of). Eg, if you have

```js
let myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const iterator = myArr.values();
for (const value of iterator) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

you may as well just iterate over the array directly:

```js
let myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
for (const value of myArr) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

> In JavaScript an iterator is an object which defines a sequence and
>   potentially a return value upon its termination. More specifically an
>   iterator is any object which implements the Iterator.

Also good explain is here

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-array-values/

Answer (score 0):

> By default, using arr[Symbol.iterator] will return the values()
>   function.

[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@iterator)